# Why Jenkins cannot run a compiled jar file

Tags: java, continuous-integration, jenkins

Inside Jenkins, I already setup a build.xml to use Ant to compile the Java code and output as a jar.
I can run the compiled jar without problem in command line.
However, after letting Jenkins to run the same jar file, I met an error "[exec] Error: Could not find or load main class".

I checked the classpath in these two situations (in command-line vs. in Jenkins) and got identical results.

This is so bizarre. My Jenkins is the latest long-term-support version and Java is 1.7.

Comment: How were you checking the Jenkins classpath ?

Comment: I believe the Jenkins server runs builds in a different environment... Thus, it may be the case that although the classpath on the jenkins server is correct, you are missing the libraries in the JVM that Jenkins is running the build in ?

Comment: I used a bash script to call my compiled class in a jar. In the bash script, I added a echo ${CLASSPATH} command.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the results from running your script via the command-line, and then the Jenkins output from the Console page?

Comment: Finally figured out the reason. I have a file that can be accessed by group members. However, Jenkins used its own account (cannot access that file needed by running the program). After granting access right to the Jenkins, my program (bash script) can run without any problem.

Comment: i would suggest answering your own question here :  this is  a usefull lesson

Comment: jayunit100 is right @Leo5188. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the reason. I have a file that can be accessed by group members. However, Jenkins used its own account (cannot access that file needed for running the program). After granting access right to the Jenkins, my program (bash script) can run without any problem.